# Struggling With Arduino

Tags: c#, .net, arduino, baud-rate

I am enjoying programming in Visual Studio 2012 Express with the C# language, and have purchased an Arduino Uno.

I have read a couple of tutorials on how to get Visual Studio to work the Uno directly, but ones like [this article](http://www.instructables.com/id/Controll-Leds-With-an-Arduino-From-a-C-Program/) have lines in it such as:

```
serialPort1.PortName = "COM4"
serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
```

When I am putting them into my test application, I am using the *System.IO.Ports;* but the *serialPort1* does not recognise. Even when I make it a String value, then the *PortName* and *BaudRate* come up in the red.

Has anyone got a clear and detailed tutorial I can follow to get my "blink" test working on the board, or know how to fix the above please?

Comment: I have used the arduino interfaced with VS 2012 before.  I used this plugin http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/VisualMicro

Comment: "come up in the red"; are you talking about an error warning? If so, do tell the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serialPort1` is most likely an instance of the [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. You'll have to make one of your own. For instance, you could write the following line of code to create an instance with the settings you want:

```
var port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
```

You can find more information about the class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).